# How to avoid loading low-detail imagery in Cesium?

Tags: cesiumjs

**Background**

I'm using [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/) to run a simulation while capturing images with `Viewer.canvas.toDataURL`. The simulation has some action in it, and I would like the map imagery to be completely loaded when the action starts. However, for the first few renders, the imagery is always very low detail.

I only want to capture images at 15fps, so I render at most 15fps, for the sake of efficiency. The problem is that imagery starts low-detail and only updates when I render. It takes around 75 renders for the high-detail imagery to load, meaning that the first ~5 seconds of output images are rendered with low-detail imagery.

**Question**

I would like to reduce the number of output images with low-detail imagery to less than 15, ideally 0.

How can I

a) pre-load the imagery so that it's completely loaded by the time I start rendering

or

b) use the time in between renders to load the imagery, so that I minimize the number of frames with low-detail imagery?

Or maybe there is another solution I haven't thought of yet.

**Things I've tried**

1) I've tried restricting the area of the imagery provider, to load fewer images. This causes no discernible change, and in fact it does not cause any change to `Viewer.imageryLayers._layers[0]._imageryProvider.rectangle`.

```
var Viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  imageryProvider: Cesium.BingMapsImageryProvider({
    url: 'https://dev.virtualearth.net',
    rectangle: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(
      Params.Lon - 5, Params.Lat - 5, Params.Lon + 5, Params.Lat - 5)
  })
```

2) I've tried raising the `minimumLevel` of the imagery provider, hoping that would prevent it from loading the low-detail imagery at all. Again, this doesn't fix the problem and `Viewer.imageryLayers._layers[0]._imageryProvider.minimumLevel` is unaffected, always 0.

```
var Viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
  imageryProvider: Cesium.BingMapsImageryProvider({
    url: 'https://dev.virtualearth.net',
    minimumLevel: 15
  })
});
```

**Minimal working example**

```
var Viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer')
Viewer.useDefaultRenderLoop = false;

var CameraTarget = new Cesium.ConstantPositionProperty(
  new Cesium.Cartesian3(
    -1673357.9867530654,
    -4597650.657420824,
    4077993.9927027463
  )
);
var CameraOffset = new Cesium.ConstantPositionProperty(
  new Cesium.Cartesian3(20, 2, 15)
);

var RenderInterval = 1 / 15; // seconds
var TimeDelta = 0;
var LastRenderTime = 0;

function ScreenCapture()
{
  console.log('capture');
}

function Render()
{
  var CurrentTime = Viewer.clock.currentTime.secondsOfDay;
  var TimeDelta = CurrentTime - LastRenderTime;
  if (TimeDelta > RenderInterval)
  {
    Viewer.camera.lookAt(
      CameraTarget.getValue(Viewer.clock.currentTime),
      CameraOffset.getValue(Viewer.clock.currentTime)
    );
    Viewer.render();
    LastRenderTime = CurrentTime;
  }
  else
  {
    Viewer.clock.tick();
  }

  Cesium.requestAnimationFrame(Render);
}
Cesium.requestAnimationFrame(Render);
```